# firebase security API only users that paid for subscription

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

firebase.com security API only users that paid for subscription

So lets say a user is logged in, but didn't pay for subscription to get data. So how to protect the data, so only users that paid subscription can see contents of some specific tables?

So let's say a user is logged in, but he didn't paid subscription to see content of tables:

```
protectedtable
```

so he cant access that
After he made purchase with paypal, then he can see that `protectedtable`

So every user that pay can access that table.

Are there any tutorials or how this can be done with firebase.com?

Comment: Did you try anything that is specified on this page? https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html I expect that you may need a custom authentication or token provider, to get the `haspaid` attribute into `auth`.

Comment: A custom token is a great approach here. You could also accomplish this using simple login by storing haspaid in Firebase itself and reference it via the security rules via something like `root.child('paid_accounts/'+auth.uid).exists()`